# Print foreach List<string> in Separate Class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I guess I'm confused on how to display what I have made in another class. For example I have written a SentenceList class as shown below. In my demo class when the user selects the SentenceList option in the menu, it will call the Sentencelist class, run the class, and output the result of the list. How do I go about this?

I know using ToString I can call that particular ToString and have it return whatever I need it to, But how do I use a forecach loop to show it for each item in a list, or to display a specific item in a list ie. list item 4. I tried it with ToString and wasn't able to figure that out.

So assuming I have my Demo class working with a switch case, what would be in the switch case after it was selected?

> Now I know my SentenceList Class doesn't work because of the foreach loop in it. I put that there because I was trying to solve my dilemma one step at a time by making a foreach loop that would need to be called or to make just SentenceList work. I'm new to C# and still learning how to do some basic functions.

SentenceList Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StringHandling
{
class SentenceList
{
    private String origText { get; set; }
    public List<string> tokens { get; private set; }
    public int numWords { get; private set; }
    public int avgLength { get; private set; }

    public string delims = ".?!";

    public SentenceList ( string OrigText )
    {
        origText = OrigText;
        tokens = Utility.Tokenize ( OrigText , delims );
    }

    public int CountWords ( string s )
    {
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches ( s , @"[\S]+" );
        return collection.Count;
    }

    public int AverageWords ( string s )
    {
        int avg = 0;
        string[] words = s.Split ( ' ' );
        foreach ( string word in words )
        {
            avg += word.Length;
        }
        avg = avg / ( CountWords ( origText ) );
        return avg;
    }

    public static string ToString ( string format )
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder ( );
        var i = 0;
        foreach ( string a in tokens )
            {
                i++;
                numWords = CountWords ( a );
                avgLength = AverageWords ( a );
                sb.Append ( string.Format ( "Sentence {0}. \n\n {1} \n\n Number of Words: {2}        Average Word Length: {3}" , i , a , numWords , avgLength ) ).AppendLine ( );
            }
        return sb.ToString ( );
    }  

}
}
```

Demo Class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StringHandling
{
enum Choices
{
    TEXT = 1 ,
    DISTINCTWORD ,
    WORD ,
    SENTENCE ,
    SENTENCELIST ,
    PARAGRAPH ,
    PARAGRAPHLIST ,
    QUIT
}


class Demo
{
    static void Main ( string [ ] args )
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Title = "String Handling Demonstration Application";
        Console.Clear ( );

        Utility.WelcomeMessage ( "Hello" );

        string filePath = "text.txt";

        if ( !File.Exists ( filePath ) )
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException ( " The file '{0}' was not found and could not be opened." , filePath );
        }
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText ( filePath );
        string origText = sr.ReadToEnd ( );

        Menu menu = new Menu ( "String Choices" );
        menu = menu + "Text" + "DistinctWords" + "Words" + "Sentence" + "SentenceList" + "Paragraph" + "ParagraphList" + "Quit";

        Choices choice = ( Choices ) menu.GetChoice ( );
        while ( choice != Choices.QUIT )
        {
            switch ( choice )
            {
                case Choices.TEXT:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected TEXT" );
                    //Text text1 = new Text ( origText );
                    //Console.WriteLine ( "\nThe original text you entered was:\n\n {0}" , Text.ToString( ) );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;

                case Choices.DISTINCTWORD:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected DISTINCTWORD" );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;

                case Choices.WORD:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected WORD" );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;

                case Choices.SENTENCE:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected SENTENCE" );
                    Sentence sent1 = new Sentence ( origText );
                    Console.WriteLine ( "Stuff" );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;

                case Choices.SENTENCELIST:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected SENTENCELIST" );
                    SentenceList sent2 = new SentenceList ( origText );
                    Console.WriteLine ( SentenceList.ToString ( "" ) );
                    break;

                case Choices.PARAGRAPH:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected PARAGRAPH" );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;

                case Choices.PARAGRAPHLIST:
                    Console.WriteLine ( "You selected PARAGRAPHLIST" );
                    Utility.PressAnyKey ( );
                    break;
            }  // end of switch

            choice = ( Choices ) menu.GetChoice ( );
        }  // end of while

        Utility.GoodbyeMessage ( "Thank you for using our application." );

    }  // end of main
}
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `String.Join(",",tokens)` ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the exact problem you're experiencing. Also, the code you provided wouldn't compile, there's a `foreach` loop right in the middle of the class, outside of a method.

Comment: No in my Demo class which is the second piece of code i want to print out the sentence list class in a foreach loop. The foreach loop is in the middle of the SentenceClass because i was trying to figure it out as if the sentence class would run alone. SO Im trying to figure out to print all the sentences in a paragraph out using the sentencelist class

Comment: I have continued to work on this problem for several hours with no luck. Maybe I haven't been clear enough on here either. All im trying to figure out is how I would put my Foreach loop that is in my **SentenceList** class in my **Demo** class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood you correctly, But here's my take:
You want to display various string representations of list items in `SentenceList` class in your `Demo` class. If that's the case, I'd go with a `ToString()` method which accepts a format parameter and then I write a `switch-case` on that parameter. Something like below in my `SentenceList` class:

```
public string ToString(string format)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    switch (format)
    {
        case "a":
            var i = 0;
            foreach (string a in tokens)
            {   
                i++;
                numWords = CountWords(a);
                avgLength = AverageWords (a);
                sb.Append(string.Format("Sentence {0}. \n\n {1} \n\n Number of Words: {2}        Average Word Length: {3}" , i , a , numWords , avgLength)).AppendLine();
            }
          break;
        case "b":
          // Another representation here.
          break;
        default:
          // default format
          break;
    }

return sb.ToString();
}
```

and use something like `Console.WriteLine(mySentenceList.ToString("a"));` in my `Demo` class.

Comment: I believe this answers most of my question. Not exactly what i meant but i think it answers what i was trying to figure out so thank you. How would i use this if i wanted to print a specific token in a list? Like list item number 3?

Comment: well, maybe another overload which accepts an index as well. like `public string ToString(string format, int index)`.

Comment: So im still not getting this i added my whole demo code My error im getting is in vs2010 - Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'StringHandling.SentenceList.tokens.get' I:\Class\CSCI 2210\Projects\StringHandling\StringHandling\SentenceList.cs 64 35 StringHandling

Comment: Check the usage of tokens. Seems like it is used somewhere (a foreach list on members maybe) before initializing. One quick fix might be adding `tokens = new List<string>()` in SentenceList ctor.

Comment: Ok thank you very much i was able to use all this to figure it out. Great learning experience!